# Error to get setOnclickListener of my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I make two fragment, one of them to Login another one is Register, during play my app when i change fragment to register my app shows me error, in Register fragment i assign setOnclickListner to a button and my app shows error in this line.

Error for setOnClickListener:
java.lang.NullPointerException

MainActivity Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    manager = getFragmentManager();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    login = new FragmentLogin();
    register = new FragmentRegister();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, login);
    transaction.commit();
    LoginPage = true;

    txtChangePage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoginRegister);
    txtChangePage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ChangePage();
        }
    });
}

public void ChangePage() {
    transaction2 = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (LoginPage) {
        transaction2.replace(R.id.fragment_container, register);
        txtChangePage.setText("Aleardy a member? Login");
        LoginPage = false;

       registerBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
       registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText userName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UsernameRegister);
                EditText password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordRegister);
                EditText confirmPassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPasswordRegister);

DataModel userData=new DataModel(MainActivity.this);
                                 userData.addUser(userName.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());         
     });

    } else {
        transaction2.replace(R.id.fragment_container, login);
        txtChangePage.setText("No account yet? Create One");
        LoginPage = true;
    }
    transaction2.commit();

}
```

I'd appreciate to help me to understand what's going wrong

Comment: Wait, where is your `Fragment` code. You can not access the `Views` of your `Fragment` if it's not created. I can see that you are trying to access them in the `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: I made it, it Only inflate a view